# Excel VBA to refresh from MySQL

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code to refresh my connections from excel to MySQL, I made it in such a way when someone tries to refresh in a PC that is not in the network it would throw a msg saying sever connection lost..

It only does the refresh part but when I use the excel file in a PC not connected to the network it doesn't show my custom message.

```
Sub refreshall()

Dim answer As Integer
Dim wSheet As Worksheet
On Error GoTo Handler

answer = MsgBox("Refresh All Sheets At Once?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Refresh All")

If answer = vbYes Then

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each wSheet In Worksheets
wSheet.Unprotect Password:="Secret"
Next wSheet

ActiveWorkbook.refreshall

For Each wSheet In Worksheets
wSheet.Protect Password:="123", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
AllowFiltering:=True, _
AllowSorting:=True, _
AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
Next wSheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

Else
Exit Sub
End If
Exit Sub

Handler:
For Each wSheet In Worksheets
wSheet.Protect Password:="123", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
AllowFiltering:=True, _
AllowSorting:=True, _
AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
Next wSheet
MsgBox "Server Connection Lost...", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Warning"
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect an error isn't being thrown and the handler code never executes. Have you tried stepping through it in debug?

Comment: You are correct no error is being thrown :(..I am confused now ActiveWorkbook.refreshall will this refresh query from MySQL..

Answer (score -1):

As I understand, exactly **ActiveWorkbook.refreshall** throws handler section when your PC is connected to the network.
I guess Excel itself detects that there is no network and don't execute some part of its own algorithms inside of **RefreshAll** sub so **ActiveWorkbook.refreshall** execution in this case causes no exeptions.